# Is $x^2+1$ irreducible over a cyclotomic field?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, factoring, extension-field

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$, where $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$, let $f(X)=X^2+1$. How can i prove irreducibility of $f$ over $K$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This polynomial is irreducible if and only if it has no roots in the field. That is true for any polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$.

Showing that $x^2+1=0$ has no root should be essentially a calculation. Check whether the square of $s+\omega t$ can be equal to $-1$ for rational $s$ and $t$. Equivalently, check whether we can have $(a+b\sqrt{-3})^2=-1$ for some rational $a$ and $b$.

**Added:** We have $(a+b\sqrt{-3})^2=a^2-3b^2+2ab\sqrt{-3}$. If this is $-1$, then $ab=0$. But $b=0$ is impossible, since we cannot have $a^2=-1$. And $a=0$ is impossible, else we would have $3b^2=1$. This cannot happen, since $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. A proof of irrationality can, if necessary, be given along the same lines as the familiar proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Why $(a+b\sqrt{-3})^2$?

Comment: The roots of $\y^2+y+1=0$ are $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. Call one of them $\omega$. The field $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ turns out to consist of all objects of the form $s+\omega t$, where $s$ and $t$ range over the rationals. This is the same collection as the numbers $a+b\sqrt{-3}$, where $a$ and $b$ range over the rationals. Squaring is less messy if you use this version. But you can work with the other. The proof will be almost the same, but will feel harder.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, prove first the possibly easier fact that $g(x) = x^{2} + x + 1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$. This is clear, as the roots of $g(x)$ are
$$
\omega, \omega^{2} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2} \notin \Bbb{Q}(i).
$$

So we have
$$
\lvert \Bbb{Q}(i, \omega) : \Bbb{Q} \rvert
=
\lvert (\Bbb{Q}(i)) (\omega) : \Bbb{Q}(i) \rvert
\cdot
\lvert \Bbb{Q}(i) : \Bbb{Q} \rvert
=
2 \cdot 2 = 4.
$$
It follows that
$$
\lvert (\Bbb{Q}(\omega))(i) : \Bbb{Q}(\omega) \rvert
=
\frac{\lvert \Bbb{Q}(i, \omega): \Bbb{Q} \rvert}{\lvert  \Bbb{Q}(\omega) : \Bbb{Q} \rvert} = \frac{4}{2} = 2,
$$
which means $x^{2} + 1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$.